# Design pattern for saving entities into database

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have a class similar to the below (C#):

```
public class Product {

    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}

    public void Save() {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Product.....";
        Database.Execute(sql);
    }

    public void Delete() {
        string sql = "DELETE Product WHERE.....";
        Database.Execute(sql);
    }
}
```

My main concern is that the code above violates SOLID principles, since it takes responsibility for creating and deleting itself.

Perhaps these Save and Delete methods should be placed somewhere outside the Product entity (Factory/Repository maybe?).

Comment: What's the question?  Sounds like you know what you need to do.

Comment: If you look at existing well thought out ORMs out there you will see that most of them (if not all) have a context that is responsible for all the actual operations and the entities themselves have no knowledge of the store they belong to or were materialized from or are updated to etc. If you insist on reinventing the wheel I would study these ORMs and duplicate what you feel you need.

Comment: Object Relational Mapping, Query Objects, Unit of Work/Repository. All these patterns are designed and well tested for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would introduce your model entity, a command and query pattern and a database layer or repository.

Your model is your `Product` and this object should be a plain object:

```
public class Product : IEntity {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Next I would create a command and query interface for working with this entity:

```
public interface ICommand {} // Marker interface

public interface IQuery<TResult> {} // Marker interface
```

Next define the handlers for `ICommand` and `IQuery`:

```
public interface IHandleQuery<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult> 
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}

public interface IHandleCommand<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Now you have a clear indication and separation of your write (command) and read (query) sides.

This means we can create a command and its handler for saving your `Product` like:

```
public class SaveProduct : ICommand 
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public double Price { get; private set; }

    public SaveProduct(string name, double price) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }
}

public class HandleSaveProduct : IHandleCommand<SaveProduct> 
{
    private readonly IRepository<Product> _productRepository;

    public HandleSaveProduct(IRepository<Product> productRepository) 
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public void Handle(SaveProduct command) 
    {
        var product = new Product {
            Name = command.Name,
            Price = command.Price
        };

        _productRepository.Save(product);
    }
}
```

> In the above we have defined an repository for handling this entity,
>   you can however depend directly on your database context here and do
>   the queries/commands to it or you can implement the repository pattern
>   using an `GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>` or just
>   the separate product repository:

```
public interface IEntity { } // Marker interface

public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity 
{
    TEntity Get(object primaryKey);

    void Save(TEntity entity); // should handle both new and updating entities

    void Delete(TEntity entity);

}

public class ProductRepository : IRepository<Product> 
{
    public Product Get(object primaryKey) 
    {
        // Database method for getting Product
    }

    public void Save(Product entity) 
    {
        // Database method for saving Product
    }

    public void Delete(Product entity) 
    {
        // Database method for deleting Product
    }
}
```

You should never return your Product entity to your UI, but use a view model, e.g:

```
public class ProductViewModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime Whatever { get; set; }
}

public class GetProductById : IQuery<ProductViewModel>
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public GetProductById(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class HandleGetProductById : IHandleQuery<GetProductById, ProductViewModel>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Product> _productRepository;

    public HandleGetProductById(IRepository<Product> productRepository) 
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public ProductViewModel Handle(GetProductById query)
    {
        var product = _productRepository.Get(query.Id);
        return product.Select(x => new ProductViewModel {
            Name = x.Name,
            Price = x.Price;
        });
    }
}
```

Please note this is written in notepad, might not compile 100%, but you should get the idea on how the separation of the various components should be in order to follow SOLID. :-)

Comment: Looks very professional! Could you elaborate on command and query pattern, why is that for?
Didn’t we fit SOLID after the CRUD operations have been moved into Repository?

Comment: I would recommend you read the articles: https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91 and https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92 which explains this pattern in depth :-)

Comment: Command/Query is often an unnecessary complexity. Please don't suggest this sort of advanced pattern without knowing the context which justifies it's overhead.

Comment: I would not say its unnessary, since the OP is asking about how to use the SOLID principles. This example shows how to to that.

Comment: @janhartmann The OP *said* "SOLID principles" but I think he really just means Single Responsibility since he mentioned the word "responsibility" and his example is clearly about moving the persistence responsibility out of the model object. It looks like a fine example to me. I'm just saying it's maybe not needed. And IMO, C/Q are often not needed. See my answer: Command and Query often falls into the same trap as Repositories and Services - they create wonderful abstractions which are used at most once or twice.

Comment: @janhartmann I'm not saying it's a bad idea - there are plenty of good reasons you may want to do this. But we don't know what the OP needs. So his question isn't very clear, but I think we can get the gist of it. He just needs a simple Repo/`ISession` contract. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Facade pattern will do just fine in your case. The Facade pattern is also known as Service Layer.

In your case you will basically have a service(a class) which will have all the methods you need. Your service should look something like this.

```
class ProductService 
{
    public void Save(Product product)
    {
       // SAVE THE PRODUCT
    }

    public void Delete(Product product)
    {
        // DELETE PRODUCT
    }
}
```

You want to inject your class where you want to save or delete products. This way all the work you have to do will be in a separate class and your code will become much cleaner.
It's also a good idea to have all those insert and delete statemenets in stored procedures.

Comment: While your code is ok, you're messing the concepts around. Your service is basically a Repository which is also a Facade. A service layer has nothing to do with the Facade pattern. They are apples and oranges.

Comment: @MikeSW, So what would be the correct implementation with Repository (or whatever)?

Comment: I believe Service Layer and Facade are different patterns. Can you point the source that says Facade is an alias for Service Layer?

Comment: Don't get too hung up on the semantics of particular patterns. You simply want some abstraction which looks after the responsibilities of the storage system (database, text file, who knows) that specifically includes saving, deleting and perhaps loading and simple query functions. We often just call these [ORMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET). See [my answer for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36939115/56145).

Comment: @cottsak, point taken. Still the phrasing should be improved not to teach fallacies.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want some sort of [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) like contract. You've already alluded to it in your [kind of] question. The link is for reference - I'm *not* suggesting you implement one. Why?

Because like @Igor said, if you're using an ORM then you'll get this contract for free. For example, NHibernate has an `ISession` with `Query<T>()`, `Save()`, `Delete()`, etc methods. This is all you need.

Nearly every project I've worked on where some abstraction over this "infrastructure" ORM contract is used (service/repository/etc), the said abstraction is weak and only serves to create more code to maintain and a higher risk of tech debt and bugs.

Take the pragmatic approach:

- Don't reinvent the wheel by creating a Repository/ORM abstraction of your own with ADO.NET calls inside. Use a solid ORM like [Fluent NHibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentNHibernate/) which makes mapping simple and interacting with the data easy (other perfectly sound alternatives might be Entity Framework, etc). If that's too much party for you, try something really simple like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) - it's a very lightweight ORM which maps to your models like freaking magic and you can still write all your own SQL. You'll get your ORM contract interface to use, which I believe is what you're asking for here, and you can get on with building out your app, rather than pondering about over engineering.
- Keep stuff simple by using your ORM contract in your controllers ('controllers' doesn't have to be MVC Controllers, it can be whatever the UI entry point for your app is. Remember: avoid unnecessary abstractions). [Here are some simple examples.](https://github.com/cottsak/mvc6webapicompare/blob/master/webapi2/SocksDrawer/Controllers/DrawerController.cs)
- Folks want to [keep things DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but the bizarre addiction developers have to #reusingallthethings means they often have Repositories or Services which wrap a perfectly fine ORM contract call and often only have one or two usages. Forget about reuse! Use the [Rule of Three](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rule-of-three/) and start by having your queries, save and delete logic in your controllers and only extract reusable code when you know you need to.
  I know [these examples are
  trivial](https://github.com/cottsak/mvc6webapicompare/blob/master/webapi2/SocksDrawer/Controllers/DrawerController.cs),
  but just imagine you needed to return some data and the query
  required some long linq expression or complex select with joins. Now imagine you needed this same query in a few places (it happens. Not often, but you will have some) - **copy and paste it!** Yes that's right; you can't believe I said it but I did. Leave that identical 10 lines copied and pasted in 2, 3 or 4 places in your code. It's totally ok. No one will die. You don't need a query object or a Repository method as long as the linq expression itself (`GetTop15TransactionsWithoutFeesExcludingCreditsGroupByDayRecentAtTop()` anyone?).

HTH.